# Python, selenium - How can I run the script without showing the browser window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless

How can I run selenium code without showing the browser(the code run but the browser window vouldn't show)?

Comment: Are you asking about headless mode?

Comment: I don't know I vould just like to run the script without it showing my browser

Comment: what browser? chrome?

Comment: yes, chrome is my main browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use headless mode, which runs the Selenium script without showing the browser.

To run chrome-headless just add --headless via `chrome_options.add_argument` like the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") # linux only
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized");
# chrome_options.headless = True # also works
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```